# Unable to open designer view in visual studio xamarin

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

i have an existing project on others pc, however, when i move the project files into another computer, the project itself unable to show the drag and drop view in the xaml file, it show the code view instead of drag and drop, how should i do to make let me see the designer view??

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Core Framework of xamarin or Xamarin Forms ? (I'm asking because you are talking about xaml files instead of xml)

If you are using the Core Framework juste have a look to this link coming from the xamarin documentation :

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/designer_overview/designer_walkthrough/

One last thing, instead of copying the files use a version management tools if is not the case (like github or bitbucket)

Answer (score 0):

The installed Android SDK is probably too old. Consider updating it.